PI 4B stopped working after I possibly shorted 5V from USB PSU to USB ground casing. Any fixes?
I had the Adafruit RGB Matrix Bonnet using the GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi 4B connecting to a 64x64 LED matrix. Everything was working well.
Then I decided to try and add a little fan from an old PI case to the setup. Because the GPIO pins were taken, I connected a little USB PSU from a circuitboard kit to provide power. (Note: I do not mean the power supply to the RPi, rather I am talking about the little breadboard power supply I used to power the fan) I connected the both wires from the fan to the PSU and the fan worked. I turned off the PSU and tried to position the fan loosely sitting on top of the setup.
When I tried to turn it back on, it didn't work. The SSH client I had opened froze. All pings to the IP don't return. The micro-HDMI won't show anything. I tried restarting multiple times and the same. The red LED stays on when the power is on, but the green one only flashes once when I turn it on.
I believe that the pins from the small PSU circuit board may have touched a part of the Raspberry Pi, particularly the USB ground casing, causing it to short. Although the fan was separate from the PSU by a few inches, it's conductors could have made contact on accident. I'm not really sure whether or not they did.
I've found a few people saying shorts shouldn't ruin a Pi. Some suggest letting it rest for a day. However, most cases suggest this protection comes as a feature of the GPIO ports.
The facts

The green light doesn't blink multiple times in the absence of an SD card.
Tried to re-flash SD card. No result.
Tried to boot a recovery USB from rpi-imager. No result.
Tried to cool the USB for multiple hours. No result.
Confirmed 5V to ground makes a complete circuit using the USB casing as ground. (I don't have a multi-meter so I wasn't able to measure voltage.)

Is my Raspberry Pi 4B toast? Is there any repairing it?
Or should I just give up and buy a new one? Thanks.

you said that you shorted out the power supply ... why is your first thought that the Raspberry Pi  is defective?

I don't know that I shorted out the power supply. But that was the only explanation I could come to. Also I really need to update my question to be more clear: I am not talking about the power supply to the the raspberry Pi with the USB-C port. I mean an external breadboard power supply I was using to power the fan that I connected to the USB 2.0 port of the raspberry pi.

And part of my question is not whether the short protection on the Rasberry Pi was faulty, but rather whether the protection applies to a USB device coming into contact with the casing.
